# Retrieve n items from each group in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get N items out of each group from a list in typescript.In c# using linq I would do something like this but I am not sure how to do it in TypeScript.

```
var rr = db.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductSubTypeCategoryId).Select(g => new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g.Take(4).ToList() });
```

My model is

```js
const lstTrade : Trade [] = [
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12}, 
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12},
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20}
];
```

and I have a list of Trade items.Now what I want to achieve is to get only 2 items from above list with distinct contract Name.In this case two items of Contract1 and two items of Contract2.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your input and expected output?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Is your end output like `[[contract1 objs], [contract2 objs]]`? If a `contractName` has 3 different amounts should it return 3 items?

Comment: end out put should be a list containing 4 objects 2 of Contract1 and 2 of Contract2 either amount is same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Shanon is correct, but it only gives you the group by portion of the code.  I am going to provide two examples, one for GroupBy and one for Take, which when used together should solve the issue for you.

Also please note that the GroupBy and Take examples I am showing are not mine.  The credit goes to this page http://complexitymaze.com/2014/04/03/cheat-sheet-from-basic-linq-to-javascript/ which I think you will find very helpful for many other LINQ type tasks in javascript (just to be clear, using javascript is the way you work with Arrays in typescript)

## GroupBy

### C#

```
var result = persons.GroupBy(person => person.lastname);
```

### typescript

```
let result = persons.reduce((previous, person) => {
    (previous[person.lastname] = previous[person.lastname] || []).push(person);
    return previous;
}, []);
```

## Take

### C#

```
var result = persons.Take(2);
```

### typescript

```
let result = persons.slice(0, 2);
```

so for your case I would write the following

```
const lstTrade : Trade [] = [
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12}, 
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12},
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20}
];

let result = lstTrade.reduce((previous, trade) => {
    (previous[trade.contractName] = previous[trade.contractName] || []).push(trade);
    return previous;
}, [])
// now it is an object with groupedTrades as properties but we want to only get a certain number of items in each group
for (const groupName in result) {
    result[groupName] = result[groupName].slice(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ccamac for your reply.It returns the grouped result fine but when I use slice it returns empty result

Comment: Sorry about that Nofi.  I incorrectly assumed that the reduce was producing an iterable array, but it is actually producing an object with properties.  So I have edited the answer to iterate over the properties instead.  I have tested this out and I think it is giving you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about Arrays and Collections in any language ALL possible array based problems can always be solved with reduce, here is your array reduced into an object where they're grouped by each contractName, from here you can just take however many you want from each.

```
const lstTrade = [
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12}, 
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 12},
  { contractName: 'Contract1' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20},
  { contractName: 'Contract2' ,amount : 20}
];


const intoObject = lstTrade.reduce<Record<string, typeof lstTrade>>((grouped, curr) => {
  return {...grouped, [curr.contractName]: (grouped[curr.contractName] || []).concat(curr)}
}, {})

/*
{
    Contract1: [{contractName: 'Contract1, amount: 12'}, {contractName: ....}...]
    Contract2: [...]
}
*/
```

Comment: okay it returns group of each distinct Contracts but how can I put a check to return only N number of items not all of them in the list.And can you please tell how can I loop through intoObject?